# XML conversion into a cfg file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a XML file which looks like this.

```
<settings>
    <setting id="auto_backup" value="false" />
    <setting id="exitonbackspace" value="true" />
    <setting id="hidemousepointer" value="true" />
    <setting id="nb_backup_files" value="10" />
    <setting id="refreshonload" value="true" />
    <setting id="screen2" value="false" />
    <setting id="show_batch" value="true" />
    <setting id="show_log" value="true" />
</settings>
```

I would like to run a python script on the XML which would extract the information into a cfg file.
So it would look like this.

```
auto_backup=false
exitonbackspace=true
nb_backupfiles=10
refreshonload=true
screen2=false
show_batch=true
show_log
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: What have you tried? Parse it with something like lxml and from there it's pretty simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import sys, lxml.etree

tree = lxml.etree.parse(sys.stdin)

for el in tree.findall('setting'):
    print el.attrib['id'], '=', el.attrib['value']
```

Something like this. Converts from standard input to output, so you could, assuming it's `script.py`:

```
cat settings.xml | ./script.py >> settings.cfg
```

Comment: I need it to be self contained so I can run it. Can import the file using `doc = etree.parse('settings.xml')` then using `foo = open('settings.cfg', 'w')` then foo.write to write the file. How would i work that in with the above?

Comment: You can adjust it as you want of course. Put the lines you mentioned and use write such as `foo.write("%s=%s\n" % (el.attrib['id'], el.attrib['value']))` instead of print.

Comment: got it done in the end with this code `#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import sys, lxml.etree

doc = lxml.etree.parse('settings.xml')

foo = open('settings.cfg', 'w')

for el in doc.findall('setting'):
    foo.write("%s=%s\n" % (el.attrib['id'], el.attrib['value']))
foo.close()`